# RecyclerView удаление позиции каждые 4 секунды

Tags: android, recyclerview, position, таймер

Есть RecyclerView например с 3 позициями , среди всех позиций нахожу максимум и удаляю потом среди о ставившихся позиций опять нахожу максимум и удаляю и так далее, одним словом каждые 4 секунды должно удалятся по 1 позиции

```
do{
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int max = 0;
                int iOfMax = 0;
                for (int i = 0; i < arrayP.length; i++) {
                    if (arrayP[i]  > max) {
                        max = arrayP[i];
                        iOfMax = i;
                    }
                }
                dataModels.remove(iOfMax);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }, 4000);
    }while (--bundle>0);
```

Но почему то оно удаляет через 4 секунды все полностью, что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Потому что Вы циклом создаёте N задач и все они (в количестве равном переменной `bundle`) практически одновременно выполняются через 4 сек. Уберите цикл и перезапускайте задачу в конце самой задачи:

```
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int max = 0;
            int iOfMax = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayP.length; i++) {
                if (arrayP[i]  > max) {
                    max = arrayP[i];
                    iOfMax = i;
                }
            }
            dataModels.remove(iOfMax);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            if (dataModels.size() > 0)
                 handler.postDelayed(this, 4000);
        }
    }, 4000);
```